# PreferenceActivity - garbled screen after rotation

Tags: opengl-es, android, android-preferences, hardware-acceleration

I use `PreferenceActivity` for setting of live wallpaper utilizing OpenGL ES 2.0. And quite often I get completely garbled screen for this `PreferenceActivity`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open live wallpaper preview.
2. Open preferences by tapping "*Settings...*" button
3. Activity is displayed correctly no matter how often you repeat step 2.
4. Change orientation of device while in preview.
5. Open preferences by tapping "*Settings...*" button again.
6. Screen of `PreferenceActivity` is garbled.

I have no custom code for drawing `PreferenceActivity` - only a few helper methods to initialize data.

Bug disappears after disabling h/w acceleration by setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in manifest. Apparently, scroll animation is not as smooth as with h/w acceleration.

Example of garbled screen:

[image]

Code of activity:

```
package org.package.name;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    public static final String PREFERENCES = "org.package.name";

    // Option names and default values
    public static final String OPT_AUTOROTATE = "autorotate";
    private static final boolean OPT_AUTOROTATE_DEF = true;
    public static final String OPT_FLOATING = "floating_type";
    public static final String OPT_FLOATING_DEF = "1";
    public static final String OPT_ZOOM = "zoom";
    private static final boolean OPT_ZOOM_DEF = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(PREFERENCES);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    }

    public static boolean getAutoRotate(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        return prefs.getBoolean(OPT_AUTOROTATE, OPT_AUTOROTATE_DEF);
    }

    public static int getFloatingType(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        return Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(OPT_FLOATING, OPT_FLOATING_DEF));
    }

    public static boolean getZoom(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        return prefs.getBoolean(OPT_ZOOM, OPT_ZOOM_DEF);
    }
}
```